# Gebrauch Präposition zu und an

Tags: meaning-in-context

Aus den Ausdrücken: Frage an dich, Bitte an dich… usw.

Würde es Sinn machen, zu sagen: eine Bitte zu dir, eine Frage zu dir?

Ich äußerte meinen herzlichsten Dank … zu meinen Kollegen.

Er richtete eindringliche Worte zu seinen Schüler.

Zum Beispiel das Verb sagen habe ich in verschiedenen Situationen gehört:

> Ich habe es dir gesagt/ Ich habe es zu dir gesagt.

Im ersten Satz wird nur Dativ benutzt, im zweiten wird die Präposition zu benutzt, um die Richtung zu jemandem zu bezeichnen.
Agiert hierbei das Verb *sagen* als ein Richtungsverb?

Auch: ich habe es dir geschickt/ ich habe es zu dir geschickt.

Answer (score 1):

> Würde es Sinn machen, zu sagen: eine Bitte zu dir, eine Frage zu dir.. Ich äußerte meinen herzlichsten Dank ... zu meinen Kollegen.

Nein, denn in diesem Kontext würde das *zu* nicht als Richtungsadverbial, sondern als Präpositionalobjekt verstanden werden. Vergleiche einmal:

> Er hat *zu seinen Kollegen* gesprochen.

Das ist ein Richtungsadverbial.

> Er hat sich *zu seinen Kollegen* geäußert.

Das ist ein Präpositionalobjekt. Es gibt in diesem Fall an, von wem gesprochen wird. Der entsprechende Verbalausdruck ist *sich äußern zu+‹Dat›*.

> <strike>Er richtete eindringliche Worte zu seinen Schülern.</strike>

Hier würde *zu seinen Schülern* ebenfalls als Präpositionalobjekt verstanden werden, und das, obwohl die Richtung, die in diesem Fall mit *an+‹Akk›* angeben werden **muss**, vergessen wurde. Der korrekte Ausdruck lautet z.B.

> Er richtete eindringliche Worte zu seinen Schülern an die Eltern.

Auch hier ist es wieder dasselbe, *zu seinen Schülern* gibt an, vom wem gesprochen wird.

---

Das Dativobjekt gibt an, wer von der Handlung profitiert, oder wer ihre Folgen tragen muss.

> Ich habe es dir gesagt.

Hier ist *dir* ein Dativobjekt. *Du* ist also derjenige, der Handlung *sagen* einen Vorteil hatte. Oder einen Nachteil, falls er auf das Gesagte nicht gehört hat.

> Ich habe es zu dir gesagt.

Hier ist *zu dir* hingegen ein Adverbial der Richtung. Es geht also darum, dass *du* der Empfänger des Gesagten war. Man kann sehr oft, eigentlich fast immer, die Richtung angeben, in die eine Handlung ausgeübt wird.

In deinem Beispiel macht das inhaltlich kaum einen Unterschied. Vergleiche aber mal ein anderes Beispiel:

> Ich habe es dir ins Ohr geflüstert.

Hier ist *ins Ohr* die Richtung und *du* ist derjenige, der vom Flüstern profitiert.

---

Und jetzt alles in Kombination:

> Die Direktorin gestattete ihm eindringliche Worte zu seinen Schülern an die Eltern.

- ihm — Dativobjekt — wer von ihrer Erlaubnis profitiert
- eindringliche Worte — Akkusativobjekt — was gestattet wird
- zu seinen Schülern — Präpositionalobjekt — von wem genau gesprochen wird
- an die Eltern — Richtungsadverbial — in welche Richtung die schlechten Nachrichten überbracht werden